# How to add and remove new elements such as list, input box and option selection in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a webview app with jquery that calculate GPA and I've created two buttons one of them for adding new elements and the other one to remove the elements and I'm trying to add more than one element at the same time such as the module name, credits input and the option selection also I'm wondering if there is a way to increment the module number for example there will be 5 modules as default and the last module called Module 5 so when I click add button the name should be changed to Module 6.

Edit:- I've add my java script that I am working on it based on this code:-

http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tzpg4/4/

```js
$(window).on('pageinit', function() {
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Sadd").click(function() {
   var test = $('Sc5');
        var i = $('#Sc5').size() + 1;
       
$('<li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none"><label for="Sc5">Credits:</label><input type="number" id="Sc5"  name="Sc5_' + i +'" value="" data-clear-btn="true"></li>').appendTo(test);
                i++;
                return false; 
  
    });
  });
 });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>CCE GPA Calculator</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=.80; maximum-scale=.80; minimum-scale=.80;" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/HideSpiner.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.flatui.css" />
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-rc.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="GPA1"> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/benggpacalc.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script> 
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="f"> <a data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="pop" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button" data-icon="home" title="Home" href="index.html">Home</a>
    <h1>BENG & BSc</h1>
  </div>
  <form id="form">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
      <li style="border:none">
        <h1>Module 1:</h1>
      </li>
      <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
        <label for="Sc1">Credits:</label>
        <input type="number" step="0.01" name="Sc1" id="Sc1" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
      </li>
      <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
        <label for="Sgrade1" class="select">Grade:</label>
        <select class="Sgrade1" data-theme="f" id="Sgrade1">
          <option value="-1">—</option>
          <option value="4">A</option>
          <option value="3.7">A-</option>
          <option value="3.3">B+</option>
          <option value="3">B</option>
          <option value="2.7">B-</option>
          <option value="2.3">C+</option>
          <option value="2">C</option>
          <option value="1.7">C-</option>
          <option value="1.3">D+</option>
          <option value="1">D</option
>
          <option value="0">F</option>
        </select>
      </li>
      <li style="border:none">
        <h1>Module 2:</h1>
      </li>
      <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
        <label for="Sc2">Credits:</label>
        <input type="number" step="0.01" name="Sc2" id="Sc2" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
      </li>
      <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
        <label for="Sgrade2" class="select">Grade:</label>
        <select class="Sgrade2" data-theme="f" id="Sgrade2">
          <option value="-1">—</option>
          <option value="4">A</option>
          <option value="3.7">A-</option>
          <option value="3.3">B+</option>
          <option value="3">B</option>
          <option value="2.7">B-</option>
          <option value="2.3">C+</option>
          <option value="2">C</option>
          <option value="1.7">C-</option>
          <option value="1.3">D+</option>
          <option value="1">D</option>
          <option value="0">F</option>
        </select>
      </li>
      <li style="border:none">
        <h1>Module 3:</h1>
      </li>
      <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
        <label for="Sc3">Credits:</label>
        <input type="number" step="0.01" name="Sc3" id="Sc3" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
      </li>
      <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
        <label for="Sgrade3" class="select">Grade:</label>
        <select class="Sgrade3" data-theme="f" id="Sgrade3">
          <option value="-1">—</option>
          <option value="4">A</option>
          <option value="3.7">A-</option>
          <option value="3.3">B+</option>
          <option value="3">B</option>
          <option value="2.7">B-</option>
          <option value="2.3">C+</option>
          <option value="2">C</option>
          <option value="1.7">C-</option>
          <option value="1.3">D+</option>
          <option value="1">D</option>
          <option value="0">F</option>
        </select>
      </li>
      <li style="border:none">
        <h1>Module 4:</h1>
      </li>
      <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
        <label for="Sc4">Credits:</label>
        <input type="number" step="0.01" name="Sc4" id="Sc4" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
      </li>
      <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
        <label for="Sgrade4" class="select">Grade:</label>
        <select class="Sgrade4" data-theme="f" id="Sgrade4">
          <option value="-1">—</option>
          <option value="4">A</option>
          <option value="3.7">A-</option>
          <option value="3.3">B+</option>
          <option value="3">B</option>
          <option value="2.7">B-</option>
          <option value="2.3">C+</option>
          <option value="2">C</option>
          <option value="1.7">C-</option>
          <option value="1.3">D+</option>
          <option value="1">D</option>
          <option value="0">F</option>
        </select>
      </li>
      <li style="border:none">
        <h1>Module 5:</h1>
      </li>
      <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
        <label for="Sc5">Credits:</label>
        <input type="number" step="0.01" name="Sc5" id="Sc5" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
      </li>
      <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
        <label for="Sgrade5" class="select">Grade:</label>
        <select class="Sgrade5" data-theme="f" id="Sgrade5">
          <option value="-1">—</option>
          <option value="4">A</option>
          <option value="3.7">A-</option>
          <option value="3.3">B+</option>
          <option value="3">B</option>
          <option value="2.7">B-</option>
          <option value="2.3">C+</option>
          <option value="2">C</option>
          <option value="1.7">C-</option>
          <option value="1.3">D+</option>
          <option value="1">D</option>
          <option value="0">F</option>
        </select>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-body ui-body-b" style="border:none">
        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
          <div>
            <button type="button" id="Sadd" name="Sadd" data-theme="f">Add Module</button>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-body ui-body-b" style="border:none">
        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
          <div>
            <button type="button" id="Sremove" name="Sremove" data-theme="f">Remove Module</button>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
        <label for="Sres">Your GPA:</label>
        <input type="number" step="0.01" name="Sres" id="Sres" value="" data-clear-btn="true" readonly>
      </li>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-body ui-body-b" style="border:none">
        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
          <div>
            <button type="button" id="Scal" name="Scal" data-theme="f">Calculate</button>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-body ui-body-b" style="border:none">
        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
          <div>
            <button type="reset" data-theme="d">Reset</button>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the right selector, you can get this module count (http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/nvp05cc6/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var curModules = 0;
    $("input[id^='Sc']").each(function(){
        curModules+=1;
    });
    console.log(curModules);
    console.log($("input[id^='Sc']").length);
});
```

**Edit after update**

That might work for you, a good start. You may also like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/nvp05cc6/2/ A few small changes to your HTML to make it easier to select and append items.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Sadd").click(function () {
        var lastId = $("#modules h1").length;
        var $newLabel = $("#module-1-label").clone();
        var $newSc = $("#module-1-scredit").clone();
        var $newSgrade = $("#module-1-sgrade").clone();
        $newLabel.html("<h1>Module " + (lastId+1) + ":</h1>");
        $newSc.find("label").attr("for", "Sc"+(lastId+1));
        $newSc.find("input").attr("name", "Sc"+(lastId+1)).attr("id", "Sc"+(lastId+1));
        $newSgrade.find("label").attr("for", "Sc"+(lastId+1));
        $newSgrade.find("select").attr("name", "Sc"+(lastId+1)).attr("id", "Sc"+(lastId+1));
        $("#modules").append($newLabel, $newSc, $newSgrade);
    });
});
```

Using `.clone()` can do a lot of heavy lifting for you, you just have to amend it a little for the new IDs and Names.

Comment: Where did you let the script run? I couldn't add an input in the demo @Twisty

Comment: It shows in the console, so you can see the value there. I got 5 as the count for both. You asked for how to get the next ID, so you would add 1 to the current. Use that when creating your new module.

Comment: Adding is pretty easy, when you want to Remove, which one are you removing? You have to provide some code that you have tried. No one here is going to write the code for you.

Comment: I've just wanted to create a new input when I click add button @Twisty

Comment: Based on your current format, you would be adding a new input, but in a new list item, and do you need just the Text or the text and select? There is a lot going on and you are going to have to take a stab at the code first. Also where do you want to add it, after the Add Module button or before? It's not as simple as you make it out to be, yet it also not too hard.

Comment: Yeah I need both actually text and select including the module with the number. I want them before the add button. @Twisty

Comment: Okay, I would advised editing your post and including the code you have tried and what errors you are encountering.

Comment: Cool it works as I want and thanks for helping and modifying my html @Twisty

Comment: One more thing for removing the list can I use remove method or there is another way to do that? @Twisty

Comment: @Shihab, you can use `.remove()` to remove the object. Just remember to be careful with your selector.

Comment: Ok for removing it's done but I am facing problems in appending, when I enter something in module 1 then I press add button it will copy the input that I've entered also to the new appended input box and for the select box I'm not able to choose any option in the appended select box also it copies the selected option from the module 1 select box

Comment: Two options, build all the elements raw, with minor changes for IDs and Names (like you had tried in your edit), or create a hidden template that you clone each time Add is clicked instead of the 1st set.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I'll try to do that